# difference between UIImageView.image = ... and UIimageView.layer.content =

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Two ways of set `UIImage` to A `UIImageView`:

First:

```
self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clothing.png"];
```

Second:

```
self.imageview.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([[UIImage imageNamed:@"clothing.png"] CGImage]);
```

what is the difference between the two ways?

which one is better?

In fact.What I want to do is displaying part of one PNG in UIImageView.
There are two ways:

First:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clothing.png"];
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image, rect);
self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Second:

```
self.imageview2.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([[UIImage imageNamed:@"clothing.png"] CGImage]);//way2
self.imageview2.layer.contentsRect = rect;
```

Which one is better? Why? Thanks!

Comment: First option is better then second..

Comment: If the `UIImage`'s orientation is not `UIImageOrientationUp`, you may get different result.

Comment: You can see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the better way is the first one :

```
self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clothing.png"];
```

Indeed, this is the way an `UIImageView` is built for.

For clarification, every view (`UIView`, `UIImageView`, etc) has a `.layer` property to add visual content on it. Here you're adding an image in it. You could have achieved the same result with a single `UIView`. But, in performances terms and clarity, you should (have to) use `.image` property.

**Edit :**

Even with your new edit, first option is still the better one.

Answer (score 0):

**First**:

```
 self.imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clothing.png"];
```

By using this you can directly assign your image to any UIImageView While in

**Second**:

```
self.imageview.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([[UIImage imageNamed:@"clothing.png"] CGImage]);
```

You can not assign image directly to layer. so you need to put a CGImage into a layer.

So First is best forever. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First option is better, Bridge concept is used before introduction of ARC

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but it's your responsibility to modify the image to make the `image.CGImage` draw correctly respect to `imageOrientation`, `contentMode` and so on. If you set the image with `imageView.image = image;`, it's apple's responsibility to do that.

I give you an example that causes the problem:
as `image.CGImage` doesn't contain image orientation, so if you set it directly and if the source image is not `UIImageOrientationUp`, the image will be rotated, unless you "fix the orientation" of the source image like this. (You can get a image that is not `UIImageOrientationUp`, just take a photo with your iPhone)

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    [self drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, self.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
```

Here are two screen shot, the first is set image.CGImage directly to layer.contents, the second is set image to imageView.image.
[image]
[image]

So always use `imageView.image` unless you know what you're doing.